# Exported .jar when run on other computers give "No suitable driver found for jdbc"

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, intellij-idea, jar

I made a small and simple program using IntelliJ IDEA to update content on some new columns in a MSSQL database. I downloaded the external library sqljdbc4.jar and added this to Project Settings > Libraries, as well as making sure that the library .jar is added to the output layout. I have confirmed that the sqljdbc4.jar is included to the exported .jar-file by unpacking the file on the Mac I use.

The program runs just fine on my Mac, but when I copy the .jar over to a colleague's computer, or try to run in in Windows on Parallels, we only get a ClassNotFound Exception with a following note that "No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver[server details]"

The code for the job is as following:

```
//[....]
private final static String SQL_DRIVER = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";

public SQLConnector(){

}
public boolean updateDatabase(String[] results, boolean inhouse){
    Connection conn;

    try{
        Class.forName(SQL_DRIVER);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: " + e.getMessage(), "Exception type: ClassNotFoundException", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return false;
    }
//[...]
```

The ClassNotFound-exception is what is triggered. Any ideas? If some additional information is required, please do not hesitate to request it.

EDIT: I have the sqljdbc4.jar saved in /Library/Java/Extensions, and if I remove it from there then the program also fails with the same error on my Mac. Even if I have the .jar-file stored in a /bin/-folder in my project and make sure that this file is the file added as a library. With jdbc-jar removed from Extensions, the program will still run fine when executed from IntelliJ even so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was in the settings for artifacts. When specifying details to create JAR from modules, I had previously selected "extract to the target JAR", but the correct option seemed to be "copy to the output directory and link via manifest". Doing this gave an error that a manifest already existed, so I had to go manually in and delete the META-INF folder in both "src" and in "out > production > [project name]". Then allow IntelliJ to build the artifact anew. This resulted in the sqljdbc4.jar file being added alongside my own JAR, instead of copying the sqljdbc4.jar file *into* my own JAR.

I do not know what the major difference between these two options are however....